# installing fyne package, it fails with `cannot find -lXxf86vm`

Tags: go, fyne

i was trying to run the demo code given in https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne

```
import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("Hello")

    hello := widget.NewLabel("Hello Fyne!")
    w.SetContent(container.NewVBox(
        hello,
        widget.NewButton("Hi!", func() {
            hello.SetText("Welcome :)")
        }),
    ))

    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

but it showing this error

```
go: downloading github.com/stretchr/testify v1.6.1
go: downloading gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c
go: downloading golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20210405180319-a5a99cb37ef4
 github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXxf86vm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

i am running go version go1.16.7 linux/amd64

Comment: check this out https://github.com/go-gl/glfw/issues/140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding a solution here for Ubuntu 20:04 with golang go1.16.5

I had gcc, I found I needed the following system dependencies
`sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev xorg-dev`

my makefile for build

```
build:
    go mod download
    CGO_ENABLED=1  go build -ldflags "-s -w" -o $(BINARY)
```

simple main.go

```golang
    import (
      "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    )

    func main() {
      a := app.New()
      w := a.NewWindow("Server Mon")
      w.ShowAndRun()
    }
```

when I build get a number of missing go dependencies stacktrace like

```
../../../gopkg/pkg/mod/fyne.io/fyne/v2@v2.0.4/storage/repository/parse.go:8:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package github.com/fredbi/uri (imported by fyne.io/fyne/v2/
```

theses all resolved with

```
go get fyne.io/fyne/v2/app@v2.0.4
go get fyne.io/fyne/v2/storage/repository@v2.0.4
go get fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/painter/gl@v2.0.4
go get fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/driver/glfw@v2.0.4
```

with above steps everything builds and runs

Answer (score 1):

If you're compiling on Linux you may need a few extra library headers - check out the instructions at https://developer.fyne.io/started/.
Depending on your distribution the library name will vary, but it might be named like `libXxf86vm-devel`.